# How many steps and big-O complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

```
def percentBases(dnaStrand):
    cytosine = dnaStrand.count('C')
    guanine= dnaStrand.count('G')
    adenine= dnaStrand.count('A')
    thymine= dnaStrand.count('T')
    
    percentC = round(cytosine/len(dnaStrand)*100,2)
    percentG =  round(guanine/len(dnaStrand)*100,2)
    percentA = round(adenine/len(dnaStrand)*100,2)
    percentT = round(thymine/len(dnaStrand)*100,2)
    
 
    return(percentC, percentG, percentA, percentT)
```

I have written this simple code and have been asked to record an approximate time complexity using big-O notation. I don't have a clue about big-O notation but after reading I would have a guess at:
T(n) = 8
O(8)

Please correct me if I'm wrong and try to explain to me. Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert, but think your guess is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To understand big-O time complexity of a function, you need to look at what will take more time to compute as the size of the input changes. Your input `dnaStrand` is a string, and you do two operations `count` and `len` that could potentially take more time as the length of the input increases. `len` for a string is constant ([source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), but `count` is linear, since you have to loop over the entire string to count occurrences of different substrings. So, your function is 4*O(n), or just O(n).

Answer (score -1):

Your function performs 8 operations and all of them take constant time.
So, T(n) = 8

In terms of big-o, you can write it as
T(n) = O(1) or O(c)

Comment: `len` is constant, but `count` is linear.

Comment: Bill the lizard so only the four assignment statements containing the count method are counted? And not the other four assignment statements? And is T(n) = 8 correct for the first function?